# Regex and jquery validate. Negate expression

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate, regex-negation, negate

I'm working on a addition method for the jquery validate plugin which must detect if 3 or more consecutive identical characters are entered, and prompt a message.
To do so I need to negate a regex expression. This is my method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("pwcheckconsecchars", function (value) {
    return /(.)\1\1/.test(value) // does not contain 3 consecutive identical chars
}, "The password must not contain 3 consecutive identical characters");
```

The code above shows the error message when no consecutive identical characters have been entered, so I need to negate the expression `/(.)\1\1/` so that it only appears when the error has been made.

This jsfiddle shows my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/jj50u5nd/3/

Thanks

Comment: How about `return !/(.)\1\1/.test(value);`

Comment: Regarding your jsFiddle, you should really combine all of those various regular expressions into one.  There is no need to have FIVE custom methods!  You could even incorporate the min/max length rules into it replacing seven rules at once.

Comment: @Sparky. The validation rules were set based on business requirements that I can't modify. The thing is that I'd need to show a custom message for each rule not passed. Would that be possible with just a method that gathers all rules?

Comment: @Pointy. That's not working. Any other suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Enter "AAAa1" and it's working fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/jj50u5nd/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Pointy in the comments, use a `!` character to negate or invert the result.

```
$.validator.addMethod("pwcheckconsecchars", function (value) {
    return !/(.)\1\1/.test(value); // does not contain 3 consecutive identical chars
}, "The password must not contain 3 consecutive identical characters");
```

Enter a "AAAa1" into the demo below, it satisfies enough of the other rules to demonstrate this particular method is working.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/jj50u5nd/6/**